# How to remove ForeignKey constraint in Django?

Tags: django, foreign-keys, microservices, django-migrations

I have a django application with two tables `order` and `user`. Table `order` has a column `user_id` which is foreign key to `user` table.

Now i want to migrate `user` table into a separate microservice. In order to do that i need to break foreign key constraint of `user_id` column in `order` table and keep it as a simple `integer` column.

How can this be achieved through Django migrations without dropping the existing column? (Both tables have live data in production system)

Comment: Write a `custom_migration` and delete the `field` then create a migration. Finally run `manage.py migrate`

Comment: If you do not have sensitive data, just delete that field, and re-add the one that you want

Comment: But that will lead in loss of data.